# Renaming file extension in batch

Tags: batch-file, file-extension

I've got a few files like this:

[image: files]

I'm wanting to change them all to *.gz

This is the code I've written to try to change the file extensions:

```
ren *.dat.gz.gz.gz.gz *.gz
```

But this doesn't do anything. Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/608128/how-to-batch-rename-and-remove-last-characters

Comment: @AlexK. - Actually that link did not have an optimal answer. I've since added a much simpler solution using only a single REN command :-) It is basically the same as MC ND's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ren ????????.dat.gz.* ????????.gz
```

or, if the .dat part is needed

```
ren ????????.dat.gz.* ????????.dat.gz
```

Comment: For an explanation as to why this works, see http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.gz) do (
   set "file=%%a" 
   set "file=!file:.gz.gz.gz=!"
   echo ren "%%~nxa" "!file!"
)
```

Run it from the location of the .gz files. Remove the Echo when the screen output looks right.

Answer (score 0):

It works too:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s *.gz') do (
 for /f "delims=. tokens=1" %%b in ('echo/%%~na') do (ren "%%a" "%%b.gz")
)
```