# Rename a string from the middle of another string in a batch loop?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I want to remove a known string `.doc` from the middle of a variable string `%%f` in a loop.
I have a batch file that converts a Word file to PDF:

```
echo  Converting MS Word documents to PDF . . .
cd /D "%mypath%\documents"
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir *.doc /S /B') do ( Q:\OfficeToPDF.exe "%%f" "%%f.pdf" )
```

**Problem:** The output files are named `myfile.doc.pdf` where I don't know the length of `myfile` in advance.

**--> How can I remove `.doc` from that string?**
Alternatively, *replace* `.doc.` with `.` would achieve the same goal.
I think I need [this kind of string substitution](http://scripts.dragon-it.co.uk/scripts.nsf/docs/batch-search-replace-substitute!OpenDocument&ExpandSection=3&BaseTarget=East&AutoFramed) but I can't get it to work within that `for` loop. 
It would almost be like this, but it doesn't work:

```
for [...] do ( set outname=%%f:.doc.=.% && Q:\OfficeToPDF.exe "%%f" "%outname%" )
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717482/renaming-file-extension-in-batch) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards) (as well as many other questions) but I didn't see a solution that works in a loop. I found a [Linux solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33279/how-can-i-rename-multiple-files-by-removing-a-character-or-string) for it but that doesn't directly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` replaceable parameters can include a list of delimiters to extract only part of the content in the case of file/folder references (see `for /?`)

In your case `%%~dpnf.pdf` will return the drive, path, and name of the input file, with the string `.pdf` attached.

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir *.doc /S /B') do ( Q:\OfficeToPDF.exe "%%f" "%%~dpnf.pdf" )
```

Or still better

```
for /r %%f in (*.doc) do ( Q:\OfficeToPDF.exe "%%~ff" "%%~dpnf.pdf" )
```

where `%%~ff` is the reference to the file with full path

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you. Minutes after posting my question, I found a solution `OfficeToPDF.exe "%%f" "%%~pf%%~nf.pdf"` based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/343846/20571) but yours is even more concise.

Answer (score 1):

```
...Q:\OfficeToPDF.exe "%%f" "%%~nf.pdf"
```

should solve your problem.

`~n` selects the `name` part of the filename. See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation...